# Turning an ellipse into a parabola

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, intuition

Today I was discussing circles, ellipses, hyperbolas, and parabolas in my precalculus class.  We did the usual: completing the square, finding the center and radius (radii), etc. etc.  But I like to also go a little bit deeper on this topic:

Algebraically, all these shapes are related by the fact their implicit equations are quadratic.  I like to show this relation geometrically by first drawing a circle, and then "stretching" it to make an ellipse, and then "stretching" it even further to make a parabola (point goes to infinity), and then "stretching" it *even further* to get a hyperbola.  I do this in the projective plane (I draw a big orange circle around the axes, which represents the line at infinity).  The students really like it.

But one of my more clever students asked me what is happening to the **equation** as I'm doing this stretching. So if I start with the equation of the unit circle
$$ x^2+y^2=1,$$
and then I do some stretching in the vertical direction,
$$ x^2+\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^2=1,$$
(so here stretching by a factor of $b$)
and I let $b$ get *really really big*, I should expect to get the equation
$$ x^2=1,$$
which is just two vertical lines (and that is what I get geometrically!). The students seem to intuitively understand this, and everyone is happy.

If I want to do the parabola, I need to fix the bottom-most point at the origin, so my equation changes as
$$ x^2+\left(\frac{y-b}{b}\right)^2=1.$$
Here again I let $b$ get *really really big*, but now I have no idea how to explain that what I get is **not**
$$ x^2+1=1.$$
Because, when you draw the picture, it is clear that as $b$ gets bigger and bigger, you get closer to a parabola.  But how can I show this algebraically, without going into a whole thing on limits, etc.? [This is a precalculus class.]

To summarize, my question is

> How do I show the equation $x^2+\left(\dfrac{y-b}{b}\right)^2=1$ eventually becomes the equation of a parabola as $b\rightarrow\infty$, **intuitively**? (No limits, no formal arguments please.)

Comment: You don't, since it doesn't. Whatever playing around you do with the $y$ part, we must have $|x|\le 1$.

Comment: Well I think you do get $x^2+1=1$ because $[(y-b)/b]^2$ can be rewritten as $[(y/b)-1]^2 and the limit as b approaches infinity is 1.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to check details, bu the standard picture is a circular cone, a fixed point partway along its axis, and the plane you are calling the xy plane rotating while always going through that fixed plane. In the beginning, with the plane orthogonal to the axis, you get a circle. As the plane gets closer and closer to parallel to a fixed generating line of the cone, the intersection of the cone with the plane gets closer to, and eventually becomes, a parabola.

Or, a conic section is a circle drawn on a unit sphere that is allowed to move around in space, and we use central projection onto the xy plane. When a point of the circle reaches horizontal, so that the radius of the sphere is parallel to the xy plane, the result is a parabola

Comment: I did the first analysis myself way back when I was in Precalculus. (It's one of the things that got me interested in math research.) You can write some nice equations in terms of the "cone angle" and "cutting plane angle" by keeping the origin of the cutting plane (hence, the origin relative to the conic's equation) at the point where the plane meets the cone axis. Compare these to equations you get by keeping a focus at the origin. Also, compare the equation of the directrix with the equation of the line where the cutting plane meets the plane perpendicular to the cone axis at the apex.

Comment: @Blue, my god, you are Apollonius of Perga. How have you survived all these years?

Comment: @Blue, meanwhile, I've never worked out how things such as the directrix work out with respect to either the cone or moving sphere model. So that's why I said details needed work. However, it is a nice non-formal picture.

Comment: *shhhhhhh!!!* ... I owe Archimedes money. I don't want him to know I'm here.

Comment: @Blue, our little secret.

Answer (score 2):

The matter is that you shall keep one of the vertices in $y$ ( for $x=0$) finite and constant.

So starting from the circle
$$
{{x^{\,2} } \over {r^{\,2} }} + {{y^{\,2} } \over {r^{\,2} }} = 1
$$
rewrite it as
$$
{{x^{\,2} } \over {r^{\,2} }} = 1 - {{y^{\,2} } \over {r^{\,2} }} = \left( {1 + {y \over r}} \right)\left( {1 - {y \over r}} \right)
$$

We want to keep the solution $(0,-r)$ for instance, so
$$
{{x^{\,2} } \over {r^{\,2} }} = \left( {1 + {y \over r}} \right)\left( {1 - {y \over {br}}} \right)
$$
for $b \in [1, \infty)$ will give you circle, ellipse, parabola.
Clearly , if you stretch instead both roots, you get a centered ellipse, which in the limit becomes two parallel lines.

Answer (score 0):

In the equation you have to fix the angle under you see the "width" of the ellipse (its axis parallel to $x$) from the origin. Or else as $b$ approaches infinity the apparent "width" of your ellipse from the origin, approaches zero. So we have to scale $x$ in proportion how much we move the center of the ellipse. This is one way to do this (but you can write any constant above $b$, even $a$):
$$
{\frac 1 b}{\Bigl(\frac x a\Bigr)^2}+\Bigl(\frac{y-b}b\Bigr)^2=1
$$
Now if you substitute:
$$
\frac 1 b=c
$$
Then your equation becomes:
$$
c{\Bigl(\frac x a\Bigr)^2}+(cy-1)^2=1
$$
This can be simplified to:
$$
{\Bigl(\frac x a\Bigr)^2}+cy^2-2y=0
$$
As $b$ approaches infinity, $c$ approaches zero. And now it is apparent that if $c$ approaches zero, the equation approaches some parabola's equation. It is nice to notice that when $c$ is negative, the equation becomes a hyperbola's equation. You can think of $c$ as something related to the angle of the plane @Will explained in his answer.

Comment: @AndrewUzzell What is the eccentricity in terms of $c$? Is it $1 - c$?

Comment: @SRobertJames, I didn't post this answer; I only edited it.  You should message randone.

Answer (score 0):

You say you don't want to go into limits, but I think you already are with your two parallel lines examples. You put it nicely, it's the intuitive version of it and not the formal one.

Pushing the logic forward as you propose might be a very good way to introduce the healthy fear we should all feel of applying limits intuitively: you never know what little gremlins are hidden in those nice simple equations!

By stretching your ellipse, you actually do get from

$$ x^2+\left(\frac{y-b}{b}\right)^2=1.$$

to

$$ x^2+1=1.$$

but *only* when $y\ll b$. And that is only a small bit of the whole ellipse! As you stretch, sure b becomes very large, but if you want to draw the whole shape then you must recognize that you'll have to handle values of $y$ within the whole range $[0, 2b]$.

The edge case $y\ll b$ is the bit close to the origin. Here is what it looks like when you make $b$ bigger and bigger:

The region around an origin-anchored vertex of various levels of ellipse stretchedness:
[image: The region around an origin-anchored vertex of various levels of ellipse stretchedness]

At very large $b$, it becomes the positive half y-axis, which absolutely matches $ x^2+1=1$ aka $x=0$.

---

Now to get to your larger question: how to stretch the equation into a parabola. My take is you have to go look for the gremlins, and it starts with expanding the equation:

$$ x^2+\left(\frac{y-b}{b}\right)^2=1$$

$$ x^2+\left(\frac{y}{b}-1\right)^2=1$$

$$ x^2+\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^2-2\frac{y}{b}+1=1$$

$$ x^2\color{red}{+\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^2}\color{blue}{-2\frac{y}{b}}=0$$

Here you need to recognize with your students that, while both red and blue will get smaller and smaller as $b$ becomes larger, the red term will do so much, much faster. So we can imagine a separate region, an intermediate between the full ellipse shape and the very bottom of earlier. In the former, red and blue are both forces to be respected and you can't ignore either, in the latter, they're both so small that we can pretend they're $0$ for the sake of the argument.

But in the intermediate region, red is already way small while blue is still relevant:

$$ x^2\color{red}{+ \langle\text{almost nothing}\rangle}\color{blue}{-2\frac{y}{b}}=0$$

which of course yields a recognizable parabola equation

$$ y=\frac{b}{2}x^2$$

Here is what that comparison looks like (green is the ellipse and dashed black is the parabola using the equations above. $b=10$)
[image: Here is what that comparison looks like (green is the ellipse and dashed black is the parabola using the equations above. b=10)]